# Collapsing WPF panels on a window in priority order

Tags: .net, wpf, window

I've got 3 panels arranged horizontally across a window. When the window decreases in width, I want the middle one to decrease in width first (while the outside two maintain their width), then the rightmost one to collapse, then the leftmost one. How do I achieve this in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DockPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx) seems to do what you need.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Label Content="Left Column" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="4"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Label Content="Right Column" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="4"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Middle Column" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="4"/>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Can this be extended to any arbitary priority of columns in a window?

Comment: Yes, you could add more child panels with `DockPanel.Dock="Left"` or `DockPanel.Dock="Right"`. The order in which they are added to the parent DockPanel determines the "collapsing prority".